# How do I build a model to improve CTR on campaign?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, class-imbalance, semi-supervised-learning

I am trying to build a propensity model for a client to increase the [CTR](https://www.wordstream.com/click-through-rate).

Client has the list of people who clicked in the previous campaigns but doesn't have the data on the list of people who didn't (neither they have the complete list of who all were the user to whom the campaign was sent). In short, I only have positive labels.

I am currently thinking of modelling this as one-class classification and try Algos like OneSVM, Isolation forest, etc.

Questions:

1. Has anyone tried Propensity modeling via OneClass Classification? If yes how were the results?
2. What are some of the cons of modeling it this way?

Comment: Welcome to DS StackEXchange. Please add more context to your question: what is CTR for example?